# drawing smooth line in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Well guys I searched a lot to find how to draw a smooth line for given points. First of all I had a file with this values

```
35,9.662
30,9.074
25,8.21
20,7.45
15,6.3
10,5.34
7,4.61
4,3.31
21,7.77
```

Then I tried to draw a smooth line using this code

```
x, y = np.loadtxt('design', delimiter = ',', unpack = True)
xSmooth = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(),300)
ySmooth = spline(x,y,xSmooth)
```

When I `print(ySmooth)` it prints an array with all the elements `0`. What should I do?

Comment: interestingly I just googled `matplotlib plot line` and found several useful hits on the first search page. See e.g. https://www.oreilly.com/learning/simple-line-plots-with-matplotlib

Comment: Yea but it does not work as it should be. As I said y values are always 0

Comment: Ah, my bad! Your `x` values must be increasing.

Comment: that helped thx